# Java: Login screen using the MVP model

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently trying to make a Login screen using the MVP model in Java.

I tried making a grid (javafx.scene.layout.GridPane) and then placing it within the BorderPane to make a nice looking layout. But on running the code the screen remains empty. I only get a screen with a title.

Here is my code:
1. View

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;


public class View extends BorderPane{
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Text scenetitle = new Text();
    Label userName = new Label();
    TextField userTextField = new TextField();
    Label pw = new Label();
    PasswordField pwBox = new PasswordField();
    Button btn = new Button();
    HBox hbBtn = new HBox();
    final Text actiontarget = new Text();


public View() {
    initialiseNodes();
    layoutNodes();
}

private void initialiseNodes() {
   scenetitle = new Text("Welcome");
   userName = new Label("User Name: ");
   pw = new Label("Password:");
   btn = new Button("Sign in");
   scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
   hbBtn = new HBox(10);
}

private void layoutNodes() {
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25,25,25,25));
    grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);
    grid.add(userName, 0, 1);
    grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);
    grid.add(pw, 0, 2);
    grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);
    grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 6);
    grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(grid, Pos.CENTER);
}
}
```

Presenter:

```
public class Presenter {
private Model model;
private View view;

public Presenter(Model model, View view) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;
    updateView();
    handleEvents();
}

private void updateView() {

}

private void handleEvents() {

}
}
```

Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Login extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
   Model model = new Model();
   View view = new View();
   new Presenter(model, view);
   Scene scene = new Scene(view);

    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never add the grid to the border pane:

```
private void layoutNodes() {
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25,25,25,25));
    grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);
    grid.add(userName, 0, 1);
    grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);
    grid.add(pw, 0, 2);
    grid.add(pwBox, 1, 2);
    grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 6);
    grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(grid, Pos.CENTER);

    this.setCenter(grid);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!